# C# Async Http request, How to stop skipping?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

```
List<string> urls = this.populateRequestList();

this.Logger("Starting");

var reqs = urls.Select<string, WebRequest>(HttpWebRequest.Create).ToArray();
var iars = reqs.Select(req => req.BeginGetResponse(null, null)).ToArray();
var rsps = reqs.Select((req, i) => req.EndGetResponse(iars[i])).ToArray();

this.Logger("Done");
```

**Things I noticed so far:**
When I run this code, "Starting" shows up in my log, but "Done" never shows up. When I view the whole process in the debugger, it seems to skip over it like it's not even there. No exceptions are being thrown either. When `reqs.Select` is looping through `req.EndGetResponse(iars[i])`, it's like it freezes or skips over stuff. When I view it in the debugger, I don't get past 10-15 loops before it just skips to the end.

**Questions:**
How do I stop this from "skipping" sometime during `var rsps = reqs.Select((req, i) => req.EndGetResponse(iars[i])).ToArray();`?

How to I get the html from `rsps`? I think this problem doing that stems from the "skipping". I tried looping through each response and calling `Repsponse.GetResponseStream()` etc..., but nothing happens as soon as it skips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that BeginGetResponse(null, null) accepts a callback as the first argument which is invoked when the operation completes. This callback is where EndGetResponse should be called. When you call EndGetResponse, the operations are not yet completed.

Look at this article to see how aync web requests can be made in C# using iterators: http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx.

If using the task parallel library or .NET 4 you can also do this:

```
var urls = new List<string>();

            var tasks = urls.Select(url =>
                {
                    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
                    task.Start();
                    return task;
                }).ToArray();

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                using (var response = task.Result)
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }                                
            }
```

Comment: Ahhhh that was the key, thank you. I was having difficulty following the async examples until I read what you said here about the callback. On a side note, I couldn't fully test your code as it threw an exception saying something about task.Start() not able to do something with null.

Comment: It's [perfectly normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228967.aspx) to call `End*` to (synchronously) wait for an asynchronous operation to complete. The call to `Start` is unnecessary; `FromAsync` returns an already-started `Task`.

Comment: task.Start() will result in exception in the given example, because Task.FromAsync starts tasks for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the asynchronous request methods to do a synchronous request, that doesn't work.

You are supposed to start the requests using `BeginGetResponse` with a callback method that handles each response. If you call `EndGetResponse` immediately after `BeginGetResponse`, it will fail because the response haven't started to arrive yet.

If you want to make a synchronous request, use the `GetResponse` method instead.

Comment: It's [perfectly normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228967.aspx) to call `End*` to (synchronously) wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

As I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.endgetresponse.aspx you need to wait for the callback before you can use EndGetResponse?

Or use GetReponse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: It's [perfectly normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228967.aspx) to call `End*` to (synchronously) wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.